# R Shiny SIZE / WIDTH OF FILTERS WHEN USING RENDER DATA TABLE

Tags: r, filter, datatable, width, shiny

I'm using renderDataTable with the filter-option.
Sometimes the values in the filter-selection-window cannot be correctly read (unless after choosing one), because the column has a smaller width.
If possible, I would like to keep the autoWidth option, and ask if there is a way to read what is  inside the filter, or if it is possible to enlarge the area of the filter-selection-window.

renderDataTable(data,filter = 'top',options = list(autoWidth = TRUE))

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBNs1.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to give more information and reproducible code of what you trying to do. What is your `server.r` and `ui.r` steps ? `options = list(autoWidth = TRUE))`, generally applies to datatable columns. Filter options are passed to `ui.r`. By, default it is autowidth. The Rshiny examples have detailed information about them in below link and hope it helps you to reach your goal.

http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/basic-datatable.html